# Size limit for GraphQL scalar String

Tags: graphql

I want to send images as Base64 encoded strings. However, the size of each generated string turns out to be very large. My question is therefore, does GraphQL restrict the scalar `String` to a certain length, i.e. is it possible for me to send my images as strings using GraphQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [last available specs](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-String), GraphQL does not restrict the scalar `String` to a certain length, i.e. it's possible for you to send it as a `String`.

Comment: I have tried it with a 30MB image file converted to base64 string. It's working fine. Thank you.